# How to open navigation drawer by clicking on option menu without creating it on toolbar?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to open navigation by just clicking on the drawer/options menu icon

Hi! I want to open the navigation drawer by clicking on the drawer icon and I am not creating a toolbar for it just put the image icon of the drawer on one side. and by clicking on that icon navigation screen appears.